# Parsing nested arrays in JSON data swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm currently working with trying to extract bits of information from a complicated json based database.  After NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData I get output like follows (some returns added for clarity)

```
 [
 "title": Recorder Suite In A Minor - Viola Concerto - Tafelmusik,     
 "estimated_weight": 85,
 "year": 0,
 "thumb": ,

"identifiers": <__NSArrayI 0x600000089970>(
{
description = Text;
type = Barcode;
value = 4891030501560;
},
{
description = Printed;
type = Barcode;
value = "4 891030 501560";
},
{
type = ASIN;
value = B0000013L9;
},
{
type = "Mould SID Code";
value = "ifpi 8412";
},
{
type = "Matrix / Runout";
value = "CD PLANT AB 8550156 CDM01";
},
{
description = "SPARS Code";
type = Other;
value = DDD;
},
{
type = "Label Code";
value = "LC 9158";
}
),
"id": 885370, 
"date_changed": 2014-06-17T03:53:03-07:00, 
"master_url": https://api.discogs.com/masters/495830, 

etc … ]
```

In particular, I need to know how to get the information out of the nested array.  Note that the array is not (obviously) a nested dictionary - given the equal signs and the repeated keys.  Any help with how to parse this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Pod like `SwiftyJSON`.

First, you need to install [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/), and then go for [SwiftyJSON](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON).

I would parse nested arrays in the following manner:

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let items = json["items"].array {
    for item in items {
        if let title = item["title"].string {
            println(title)
        }
    }
}
```

Check out the documentation and **Usage** section of SwiftyJSON for more info.

Cheers...

Comment: Why do you suggest SwiftyJSON? The OP has already parsed the JSON properly with NSJSONSerialization. The question isn't about parsing JSON. It's about how to extract the desired data from the resulting arrays/dictionaries.

Comment: The OP needs help with extracting information from a nested array. SwiftyJSON provides a clean method to parse the JSON file properly AND extract information even from a nested array.

Comment: Thanks Indeed! Swifty JSON made pulling the data out a LOT easier. . .

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. Please accept the answer so that other people can benefit too.